# Poor performance of Flux::mergeComparing

Tags: project-reactor

I'm migrating my application to Reactor and noticed weird performance issue with Flux::mergeComparing. Here's a benchmark for my existing implementation and Flux alternative.

```
@Fork(value = 1)
@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
@Measurement(iterations = 3)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public class MergeComparingBenchmark
{
    private List<List<Integer>> numbers;

    @Setup
    public void setUp()
    {
        numbers = IntStream.range(0, 1_000)
                .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, 10_000))
                .map(IntStream::boxed)
                .map(stream -> stream.collect(toList()))
                .collect(toList());
    }

    @Benchmark
    public List<Integer> myMerge()
    {
        final List<Stream<Integer>> data = numbers.stream().map(Collection::stream).collect(toList());
        final MergingIterator mergingIterator =
                new MergingIterator(data);
        return Streams.stream(mergingIterator).collect(toList());
    }

    @Benchmark
    public List<Integer> mergeComparing()
    {
        final Flux<Integer>[] data = numbers.stream().map(Flux::fromIterable)
                .toArray(Flux[]::new);
        return Flux.mergeComparing(data)
                .collectList()
                .block();
    }

    static class MergingIterator implements Iterator<Integer>
    {
        private final PriorityQueue<Tuple2<Integer, Iterator<Integer>>> queue;

        MergingIterator(final List<? extends Stream<Integer>> iterators)
        {
            this.queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(entry -> entry.v1));
            checkNotNull(iterators).stream()
                    .map(Stream::iterator)
                    .filter(Iterator::hasNext)
                    .forEach(iterator -> queue.add(Tuple.tuple(iterator.next(), iterator)));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            return !queue.isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public Integer next()
        {
            final Tuple2<Integer, Iterator<Integer>> element = queue.poll();
            final Iterator<Integer> iterator = element.v2;
            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                queue.add(Tuple.tuple(iterator.next(), iterator));
            }
            return element.v1;
        }
    }
}
```

And the results are:

```
MergeComparingBenchmark.mergeComparing  thrpt    3  0.181 ± 0.664  ops/s
MergeComparingBenchmark.myMerge         thrpt    3  5.146 ± 1.390  ops/s
```

Why is the reactor case so slow? What can I do to improve it?

I tried to change the subscriber thread pools, changing prefetch size and reactor buffers, but there was not difference.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to get a list of sorted integers, then I think you can simply call the [`collectSortedList`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collectSortedList--) method :

```java
return Flux.merge(data)
           .collectSortedList()
           .block();
```

I also don't understand why you implemented your own iterator, you basically just need to call the [`sorted`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted--) method :

```java
return numbers.stream()
              .flatMap(Collection::stream)
              .sorted()
              .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

### MergeComparing

From the [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#mergeComparing-java.util.Comparator-org.reactivestreams.Publisher...-)

> Merge data from provided Publisher sequences into an ordered merged sequence, by picking the smallest values from each source (as defined by the provided Comparator). This is not a sort(Comparator), as it doesn't consider the whole of each sequences.
> Instead, this operator considers only one value from each source and picks the smallest of all these values, then replenishes the slot for that picked source.

It only consider a single element from each sources to do the comparison :

```java
Flux<Integer> flux1 = Flux.just(9, 6, 11);
Flux<Integer> flux2 = Flux.just(10, 2, 13);

Flux.mergeComparing(flux1, flux2)
    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
    .subscribe();

/** 
  Output => 9 6 10 2 11 13 
  
  Compare 9 and 10 => 9
  Compare 6 and 10 => 6
  Compare 11 and 10 => 10
  Compare 11 and 2 => 2
  Compare 11 and 13 => 11
  => 13
**/
```

This is probably not what you need

Comment: I actually need to merge a set of sorted sequences and due to huge number of elements I can't simply collect them all into memory. The merge has to be lazily done by comparing first elements from each input sequences.